# Page view settings in Opera and custom hotkeys for Speed Dial

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, opera

How can I set Opera to remember my view settings for web pages?

I don't want to have to keep manually adjusting the view while on a webpage.

Also, how can I use hotkeys or keyboard shortcuts to access the rest of my Speed Dial pages? 10 - 25 don't have hotkeys.

Answer (score 0):

Which view settings are you adjusting? Right-clicking the page and selecting "Edit Site Preferences..." might do some of what you want, on a per-site basis. Global defaults can be adjusted via Preferences (Web Pages tab, and Content under the Advanced tab).